# Forwarding HTTP headers using Juniper

Tags: proxy, http-headers

I'm working with a sysadmin that uses a Juniper solution that behaves as a proxy. I have no idea what it is, but here's a picture of the web interface: http://imagebin.ca/v/1UKN1jGYPUWd

Through that proxy, I'm trying to use Sharepoint's REST API, unfortunately there are some headers (such as X-RequestDigest) that Juniper's proxy doesn't forward to Sharepoint.

Basically, I need the equivalent of nginx's `proxy_pass_request_headers` for Junipers' applications.

The sysadmin doesn't seem to know what HTTP header forwarding is, or how to configure it. Can anyone identify the solution he's using from the picture ? Does anyone know where to find documentation about this ?

Comment: This is a Juniper IVE SSL VPN terminator, running on a Juniper SA or MAG appliance or on a virtual machine. Juniper can be pretty close lipped about the technology without being a partner, so your best bet is to get the Sysadmin to talk to your reseller about whether it's possible. I'll also take a dig around on my one and see what I can turn up, if anything.

Answer (score 0):

Further to my comment added above, there appears to be no way to implicitly pass variables around. You can tell the current IVEOS images that the Web URL you're linking to is a Sharepoint Site, and it'll do "clever" things with the URL, but I'm not exactly sure what you want it to do, and whether they'll handle it.

Here are the screen shots for the "Sharepoint" configuration panels on the Web Resources page. As I'm not a Sharepoint Admin, I can't tell you whether these are useful to you or not.

I hope it helps!

[image: A basic view of the SharePoint Settings in IVEOS]

[image: A slightly more complex view of the SharePoint settings in IVEOS]

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for the Web Resource custom header policy
https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/sa8.0/topics/task/operational/secure-access-web-rewrite-custom-header-policy.html

Edit: The first resource became a dead link. New link: https://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/nsm2012.2/topics/task/configuration/remote-management-secure-web-resource-policy-configuring-nsm.html

Fur custom headers (to send some user information) we've used the "Web Rewriting Resource Policy"

```
SSO Cookies/Headers > General tab -> Headers and Values
to pass custom user data (user name, role, client certificate).
```

I assume you have the backend application (sharepoint) configured as the a PTP (PassthroughProxy) we bresource. I am pretty confident that only standard HTTP headers are passed to the backend by default :(

To pass all custom headers I found following book (Juniper(r) Networks Secure Access SSL VPN Configuration Guide): https://books.google.be/books?id=5OYf6u5vzFsC&pg=PA369&lpg=PA369&dq=Juniper+pass+custom+headers&source=bl&ots=s5oF5NEKjP&sig=8091EV2Pyw6pIFQifMOIR2pLpLk&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiFwpf6m_DOAhWFWRQKHXoRD0EQ6AEIPDAE

where it says
Passing custom headers can be enabled by:

```
Users > Resource Polities > Web > Custom Headers
```

This option may not be visible on the admin interface by default, it needs to be enabled:

```
Users > Resource Policy > Web > Web ACL and there's a "Customize" button
```

Comment: Don't post link only answers. Sometimes links become dead. At least copy-paste answer from the link.